# Zend Framework - Variable in Subject line of email

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, email, variables

I haven't done forms before in Zend framework. So I have my .phtml page which is setup correctly and working with my form.  I have the controller file and mailer.php file which are all working fine.  The form validates with javascript, sends an HTML email to the user.  All of that is working fine.  I usually get stuck on the easiest of things.

Below is a snapshot from my controller file, which is where the subject line is being set.

```
  $arrData = $this->_request->getPost();
  if (count($arrData) > 0) {
  $arrErrors = array();
  $objMailer = mymailer($arrData);
  $objMailer->setSubject('Subject Line');
```

That works fine, but I want to include a variable (or rather a $_POST field) in the subject line.  I have done this many times with a standard PHP form with everything on the same page.  I think my problem is that the .phtml page is posting form action to my public function in my controller file which then runs the mailer php script.

I have tried printing $arrData, nothing, to try and see if I can grab the $_POST field that I am wanting.

How can I grab the $_POST field from the original .phtml page?  I think that is the issue here.

Thanks for any help, maybe I need to take a break and come back, that usually helps.

I was able to print out the array here: print_r ($objMailer);

```
 mymailer Object
 (
[_strRecipient:mymailer:private] => 
[_strBcc:mymailer:private] => 
[_strSubject:mymailer:private] => 
[_strEmail:mymailer:private] => 
[_arrData:mymailer:private] => Array
    (
        [full_name] => brian
        [invitee_name] => test
        [email] => test@testing.com
        [captcha] => kqd2q9
    )

[_arrAttachments:mymailer:private] => 
[_blnCaptcha:mymailer:private] => 1
[_arrErrors:mymailer:private] => Array
    (
    )

 )
```

I am needing to grab the full_name field.  How can I echo/print out just the full_name field?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different ways to grab POST variables in the controller.

The basic way.

```
 $post = $this->_request->getPost()
```

I usually use this...

```
 $id = $this->_request->getParam('id', 0)
```

The getParam function will either return the value of $_POST['id']/$_GET['id'] or 0

Try

```
 $objMailer->setSubject($arrData['full_name']);
```

If that doesn't work, do a var_dump on $arrData and show the results.